# Multiple ViewModels in View asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc and viewmodels are new to me as well. I have a view that shows products.  In the view I want to show all the Products in one div.
then in another div I want to show just the featuredProducts and in another div the Toprated. I am trying to use different viewmodels for each because I am going to use these again on different page. Is this the correct way to go about doing this and if not what is.  Also how can I do this with viewmodels just for the exercise.

Domain Model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean FeaturedProduct { get; set; }
    public Boolean NewProduct { get; set; }
    public Boolean TopRated { get; set; }
    public Boolean BestSellers { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModelProductsMain (Parent)

```
public class ViewModelProductsMain 
{
    public ViewModelProducts Products{ get; set; }
    public ViewModelTopRated TopRated{ get; set; }
    public ViewModelFeatured Featured{ get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels (children)

```
public class  ViewModelProducts (Child)
//all products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelTopRated (Child)
//all products with TopRated true
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelFeatured (Child)
//all products with Featured true
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //How do I, instantiate and populate the model
    var model = new ViewModelProductsMain ();
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<myProject.ViewModels.ViewModelProductsMain >
```

Comment: No bro all your models contains same Property

Comment: A single Model can make this work

Comment: One view model named `ProductsViewModel` and then your `ViewModelProductsMain` but I suspect you really want `public IEnumerable<ProductsViewModel> Products { get; set; }` since its a collection (and maybe Featured is as well?)

Comment: unless you need different properties in Toprated and featured products there is no need to define another model.

Comment: YOu can Use Partial View also to renders different sections in single page

Comment: so, either use a partial view and render each one where I need it.  or if the models are different then I use the multiple viewmodel technique.  How do I set up the controller in this case if i want to query out different data sets for each section if they are the same model.  Do i do that i the controller ( I would love exmple)  or do I do this in the view with an if statement- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should change ViewModelProductsMain to this:

```
public class ViewModelProductsMain
    {
        public List<ViewModelProducts> Products { get; set; }

        public List<ViewModelTopRated> TopRated { get; set; }

        public List<ViewModelFeatured> Featured { get; set; }
    }
```

and for display your product in your view should write this code:

```
@model  WebApplication1.Models.ViewModelProductsMain

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="AllProducts">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Products.ToList())
    {
        @item.Name
        <hr/>
    }
</div>

<div id="TopRated">
    @foreach (var item in Model.TopRated.ToList())
    {
        @item.Name
        <hr />
    }
</div>

    <div id="Featured">
        @foreach (var item in Model.TopRated.ToList())
        {
            @item.Name
            <hr />
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i see   public int ProductId { get; set; } in all of your models. seems you have some think like Foreign Keys in your data so you can make your view model better than what we see in ViewModelProductsMain.

so:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelProducts {
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

do what you see at top to `ViewModelFeatured` and `ViewModelTopRated` to

then:

```
public class ViewModelProductsMain
{

    public ViewModelProductsMain()
    {
        this.Products = new List<ViewModelProducts>();
        this.TopRated = new List<ViewModelTopRated>();
        this.Featured = new List<ViewModelFeatured>();
    }
    public List<ViewModelProducts> Products { get; set; }

    public List<ViewModelTopRated> TopRated { get; set; }

    public List<ViewModelFeatured> Featured { get; set; }
```

}

don't forget to write a constructor for your **ViewModelProductsMain** 
if you dont make constructor ..it brings `null reference error`

Comment: I think that makes sense.  Each viewmodel is still it's own class- correct? and how do I write the constructor that is what I am still having a problem with

Comment: @dince in this case, each view model is list of specific class...and just a simple search about constructor will help you, on google..